# Extra box appears under container on hover

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm fiddling around with html and css, trying to learn some things.

Before I move on, here a [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/01poLwam/1/) that shows the problem (in its principle).

Currently, I've got this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="css/index.css">

</head>

<body>

    <div class="logo">
        <a>
            <img src="images/LogoWhiteSmall.png" alt="Hardnose Logo" target="_blank">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="message">Swimming your way</div>

</body>

</html>
```

and this is the CSS code (actually SCSS, sorry about that):

```
@import 'fontsAndColors';

/* Setting frame */

* {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: $main_font;
}

body {
    background: $hn_green;
    /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, $hn_green, $hn_blue);
    /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, $hn_green, $hn_blue);
    /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, $hn_green, $hn_blue);
    /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, $hn_green, $hn_blue);
    /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}

img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.2;
    z-index: 1;
}

.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
    :hover {
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        opacity: 1.0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
}

.message {
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: center;
    color: $hn_white;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 45%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: .2;
}
```

Now, the problem is this: when I hover the image, I just want it to pop out. That all works. However, while hovering, I appear to create a small window section underneath. So, when hovering the logo, the scrollbar shows that I can scroll down a little (see picture), while I couldn't before. Any ideas what is causing this?

[image: Problem]
Thanks!

Comment: You had better provide us with the instance on jsfiddle.

Comment: It's a little less clear in the jsfiddle, but you can see a small stretch where the gradient 'restarts' below: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/01poLwam/1/) I changed the gradient to make it more clear. It's the little grey bar at the bottom that's driving me nuts.

Comment: Probably you haven't corrected the mistakes which were mentioned. For me it works well http://joxi.ru/nAyxpzkfY9BbG2

Comment: I ran your jfiddle to get the screenshot, though. I'm on Safari, maybe that has something to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `overflow: hidden;` to the `body` element, or whatever the container element will be. That solved the problem in your JSFiddle for me.

Comment: YES! Adding it to the .logo container fixed it for me. Thanks everyone!

Comment: ) it's not good decision. Because you disable scroll forever for body. Try to add content and you will see what happen.

Comment: I get what you're saying. In this case, this page will never be more than a portal to the real main page, so it suits my needs. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: @Alexander totally, you wouldn't apply it to `body` in a practical use case. It'd be in a container div.

Comment: I added it to the .logo container to fix it, which is a div, if that's better.

Comment: @Alexander yeah, it seems to work for me in that fiddle.

Comment: @Inkidu616, check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first mistake is http://joxi.ru/EA4zdNWIwXz0Gm
The second one - add here vertical-align: top; http://joxi.ru/DmBLgXyuwqO6yA

https://jsfiddle.net/01poLwam/2/

```
    <div class="logo">
        <a>
            <img src="http://images.clipartbro.com/33/smiley-face-symbols-33397.png" alt="Hardnose Logo" target="_blank">
        </a>
    </div>

* {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif; }

/* line 28, /Users/Inkidu/Documents/Hardnose/Website/v2.0/css/index.scss */
body {
  background: #aaa;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #aaa, #000);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #aaa, #000);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #aaa, #000);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #aaa, #000);
  /* Standard syntax (must be last) */ }

/* line 41, /Users/Inkidu/Documents/Hardnose/Website/v2.0/css/index.scss */
img {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.2;
  z-index: 1; }

/* line 54, /Users/Inkidu/Documents/Hardnose/Website/v2.0/css/index.scss */
.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  /* line 59, /Users/Inkidu/Documents/Hardnose/Website/v2.0/css/index.scss */
  .logo:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: all 0.5s ease; }

/* line 70, /Users/Inkidu/Documents/Hardnose/Website/v2.0/css/index.scss */
.message {
  font-size: .8em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 45%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: .2; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I noticed that I actually copied my SCSS code, so if that's what you mean, it's probably not an error (the first one). As for the second mistake you mentioned, the problem isn't fixed yet (it actually looks worse in your jfiddle). If you hover the smiley and scroll, you'll see a large section appeared underneath :/

Comment: Are you seriously? Please check it out again https://jsfiddle.net/01poLwam/2/. It should work properly.

Comment: Yup, sorry dude. This is a screenshot of what I'm seeing on your jfiddle, when I hover and scroll down. http://imgur.com/hBRN4Z7

Comment: Probably you haven't corrected the mistakes which were mentioned. For me it works well joxi.ru/nAyxpzkfY9BbG2

Answer (score 0):

The big problem was regarding the `img` element:

1) the `img` has defined the size of the page, because the CSS rules have specified this 

2) when `.logo:hover` was activated, it affected the size of the `img`, which affected the sizeof the page(extra height => vertical scrollbar appears)

---

I solved the problem this way:

1) CSS rules for the `img` have been moved to its parent, the `a` element

2) CSS rules for `.logo:hover` have been updated so that the `scale(1.1)` function affect only it's child, the `img`

---

External demo: https://jsfiddle.net/01poLwam/4/

---

```css
* {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif; }

/* line 28, /Users/Inkidu/Documents/Hardnose/Website/v2.0/css/index.scss */
body {
  background: #aaa;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #aaa, #000);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #aaa, #000);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #aaa, #000);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #aaa, #000);
  /* Standard syntax (must be last) */ }

/* line 41, /Users/Inkidu/Documents/Hardnose/Website/v2.0/css/index.scss */
a {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.2;
  z-index: 1; }

/* line 54, /Users/Inkidu/Documents/Hardnose/Website/v2.0/css/index.scss */
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto; }
  /* line 59, /Users/Inkidu/Documents/Hardnose/Website/v2.0/css/index.scss */
  .logo :hover img{
    opacity: 1.0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: all 0.5s ease; }

/* line 70, /Users/Inkidu/Documents/Hardnose/Website/v2.0/css/index.scss */
.message {
  font-size: .8em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 45%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: .2; }
```

```html
    <div class="logo">
        <a>
            <img src="http://images.clipartbro.com/33/smiley-face-symbols-33397.png" alt="Hardnose Logo" target="_blank">
        </a>
    </div>
```